# Organic polyether with carboxyl moiety reacting with aldehyde, following reaction with sulfuric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, esters

I want to react the following molecule with conc. sulfuric acid in the presence of methanol at room temperature:

[image]

If I am right, this would make a methyl ester to be formed on the carboxyl.

The aim afterwards is to let it react with vanillin (in the presence of left over sulfuric acid) at 90°C, so it will give a coloured derivative.

Below is the structure of vanillin. As you can see, this has an aldehyde group and a hydroxy group.

[image]

Is it possible to let an aldehyde and ester react at higher temperatures?

Comment: What do you hope to get as a result of this reaction? (Also, I'm not sure the first reaction would give you the ester in good yield - there are a number of -OH that can easily be protonated, and then leave to form a carbocation, and do a number of things from there. For instance, that allylic hydroxyl looks particularly tasty for concentration sulfuric acid.)

Comment: I found these steps in a post-column derivatization reaction in HPLC. It gives a coloured molecule, but  I don't know how this would look like. I would like to know the principle, so I could use this for similar reactions in the future.

Comment: I just checked chemaxon, and it seems that the hydroxy groups have pka's that are in the range of -3 ; 12.7. So it seems that these groups will not be protonated with conc. sulfuric acid as this is only a semi-strong acid.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: do you have a link to a paper describing this? It might provide some more insight.

Comment: I don't really understand your second comment. What is the "semi-strong acid" you refer to? Sulfuric acid has a Hammett acidity of around -12 if I remember correctly - thus making it a very very strong acid. Depending on how concentrated the sulfuric acid is, it can also produce species such as pyrosulfuric acid, which is even MORE acidic. The question isn't whether or not the hydroxyls will get protonated - it's whether something else will happen faster, and lead to a more useful product.

Comment: I found a paper where they react the molecule immediately with vanillin in conc. sulfuric acid. "The derivatization reagent consisted of 20 mL concentrated sulfuric acid, 950 mL methanol and 30 g vaniline." Some papers: [link]https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259003919_The_Determination_of_Six_Ionophore_Coccidiostats_in_Feed_by_Liquid_Chromatography_with_Postcolumn_Derivatisation_and_SpectrofotometricFluorescence_Detection [link]https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10932237_Determination_of_monensin_residue_in_chicken_by_HPLC_with_post-column_derivatization

Comment: Here are the links of 2 reagents that do the trick: [link]https://www.pickeringlabs.com/products/analysis-products/reagents-chemicals/p-dimethylaminobenzaldehyde/  [link]https://www.pickeringlabs.com/products/analysis-products/reagents-chemicals/vanillin/

Comment: The papers you linked say nothing of concentrated sulfuric acid other than the following sentence: "The derivatization reagent consisted of 20 mL concentrated sulfuric acid, 950 mL methanol and 30 g vaniline." Note the volumes of the reagents!!! This is not at all what you say: "I want to react the following molecule with conc. sulfuric acid in the presence of methanol at room temperature." Rather, a more correct sentence would be to say: "I want to dissolve the following compound in acidified methanol." There should not be significant reactions going on in the first step, however, some will.

Comment: I tried to follow the references to find the first paper that mentions this vanillin/$\ce{H2SO4}$ staining, and eventually found a 1972 paper: "Automated photometric microbiological assay for monensin in poultry rations." published in "Journal - Association of Official Analytical Chemists" (which no longer exists, by the way) by Kavanagh FW and Willis M. I could not find the body of this paper - very likely it never existed in electronic form.

Comment: If I were to guess what reaction happens, it is that the carbocation at the allylic hydroxyl forms (by way of water leaving), then the ring in vanillin attacks the carbocation, forming a vanillin derivative. However, I'm not sure such a compound would be colored, as usually coloring suggests significant conjugation. The electron withdrawing effect of the carbonyl _may_ be enough to make the compound colored, but again, I'm not 100% sure.